# The wireless connection could not be detected by other computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, connection

I tried to configure router PC in my Linux Ubuntu 10.04 . I use 2 connection to connect 2 clients. The first computer uses a LAN connection and the second computer uses a wireless connection.  When I created a new wireless connection in Ubuntu, the connection could not be detected by the other computer that use wireless connection.  I have tried to use Windows and Ubuntu as a client but it doesn't work wither way.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: I don't quite understand `router pc`. You trying to configure a wlan adapter? Have you heard of hostap?

Comment: i mean configure my computer as a router.
when i wanted to connect a computer use a wireless connection, my wireless connection that i made could not be detected by other computer.

Comment: What is with hostap? You're using that?

Comment: hostap?
what is that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HostAP